# Deadlock - SQL Server 2012 TempDB

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

We have an issue with deadlock in a SQL-server agent job. Attached is the xml_deadlock_report.

We have some stored procedures that executes in the job and we use temporary tables #.

Some example:

```
SET @columnsSQL = ' SELECT @columnArrayOut = COALESCE(@columnArrayOut + '','' , '' ''  ) ' + CHAR(13)
                        +' + COLUMN_NAME '  + CHAR(13)
                        +'from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ' + CHAR(13)
                        +' where table_name = '  + CHAR(13)
                        +'  object_name(' + CHAR(13)
                        +'      object_id(''tempdb..'+ @globalTableName +'''),' + CHAR(13)
                        +'      (select database_id from sys.databases where name = ''tempdb''))' + CHAR(13)
                        +'AND COLUMN_NAME <> ''SeqNbr''' + CHAR(13)
                        +'ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION '






    SET @sqlScript  = 'INSERT INTO '+ @globalTableName + CHAR(13)
                    + 'SELECT * '+ CHAR(13)
                    + 'FROM ('+ CHAR(13)
                    + 'SELECT '+ @columnArray +', CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+ @orderBy +') AS VARCHAR) AS SeqNbr FROM '+ @TableName +' WITH (NOLOCK)'+ CHAR(13)
                    + 'UNION'+ CHAR(13)
                    + 'SELECT '+ @columnArrayHeading +', ''0'''+ CHAR(13)
                    + ') AS Temp'+ CHAR(13)
                    + 'ORDER BY CAST(SeqNbr AS INT)  ASC'+ CHAR(13)

                    + 'SELECT '+ @columnArrayOut +',  CASE convert(INT, SeqNbr) WHEN  0 THEN ''SeqNbr'' ELSE SeqNbr END
                    FROM '+ @globalTableName + CHAR(13)
                    + 'ORDER BY CAST(SeqNbr AS INT) ASC'+ CHAR(13)
                    + 'DROP TABLE '+ @globalTableName;
```

I am thinking it must be that we need to add nolock after some code, am I on the right track?

We have different customers on the same SQL-Server instance and it is SQL-Server 2012.

```
 <deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process6ff025c38" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process6ff025c38" taskpriority="0" logused="27564" waitresource="KEY: 2:281474978938880 (6f07e5ef564d)" waittime="3457" ownerId="2943291814" transactionname="ExportFilter" lasttranstarted="2015-12-28T07:15:10.007" XDES="0xdb84ad760" lockMode="S" schedulerid="3" kpid="1536" status="suspended" spid="72" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2015-12-28T07:15:09.980" lastbatchcompleted="2015-12-28T07:15:09.970" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.970" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x93F327E5D307B843A95C7883AEE52C41 : Step 2)"  isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2943291814" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="538968096" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="78" sqlhandle="0x02000000bdb8ee370644f54bc076833c46eb8ce8ae6c21370000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT @columnArrayOut = COALESCE(@columnArrayOut + ',' , ' '  ) 
 + COLUMN_NAME 
from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 where table_name = 
    object_name(
        object_id('tempdb..##w_xxx004718_2328_MG_SO'),
        (select database_id from sys.databases where name = 'tempdb'))
AND COLUMN_NAME &lt;&gt; 'SeqNbr'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION    </frame>
    <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>

  isolationlevel="read committed (2)" 
         <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="78" sqlhandle="0x020000006df5ee06624475cdc854f45d0579dd554dddd61c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    SELECT @columnArrayOut = COALESCE(@columnArrayOut + ',' , ' '  ) 
     + COLUMN_NAME 
    from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     where table_name = 
        object_name(
            object_id('tempdb..##w_xxx050820_2164_MG_LO'),
            (select database_id from sys.databases where name = 'tempdb'))
    AND COLUMN_NAME &lt;&gt; 'SeqNbr'
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION    </frame>
        <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    sp_executesql    </frame>

    <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="281474978938880" dbid="2" objectname="tempdb.sys.sysschobjs" indexname="clst" id="lock15895c380" mode="X" associatedObjectId="281474978938880">
       <owner-list>
        <owner id="processea1d7ecf8" mode="X" />
       </owner-list>
       <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process6ff025c38" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
       </waiter-list>
      </keylock>
      <keylock hobtid="281474978938880" dbid="2" objectname="tempdb.sys.sysschobjs" indexname="clst" id="lock375a18480" mode="X" associatedObjectId="281474978938880">
       <owner-list>
        <owner id="process6ff025c38" mode="X" />
       </owner-list>
       <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processea1d7ecf8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
       </waiter-list>
      </keylock>
     </resource-list>
    </deadlock>
```

Comment: can you alter the code so that it doesn't try and read from the tempdb system tables in the same transaction as it creates objects in tempdb? `nolock` might help but I've found often against system views it doesn't work. Certainly the metadata functions ignore it.

Comment: I think we will not alter the code right now. Is there any other quick fix for this? Can I use another isolation level to solve it?

Comment: your code uses `object_id` and `object_name` they will [certainly ignore the isolation level and take locks anyway](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=432497)

Comment: So there is no other solution for this problem?

Comment: It is two different SPID:s which creates the deadlock so it is differnt transactions...

Comment: Yes I know. It is nearly impossible for a single Spid to deadlock itself. But they both create objects in tempdb and hold locks open in the base table behind sys.objects and then go on to read from there.

Comment: In the current solution we call the other stored procedures from the main procedure. The SQL-agent job has only one step. But you mean if we instead split the calls down to several steps in the job we can solve the problem?

Comment: At the moment it looks like you are doing `begin tran create table #.... Select end tran`. If you commit the transaction between the create and select the locks will be released and not block each other.

Comment: What is the purpose of these global temporary tables? Creating and dropping temporary tables at high rate does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: Martin Smith: Yes, you are right there is no transaction handling in the procedures. But there is one more thing I don't understand. The lock is on the index clst in tempdb table. And there is two different customer databases that call the tempdb when the deadlock occurs. If I do transaction handling for the customer databases isn´t it a risk that deadlock occurs anyway?

Comment: Alexei: You mean that it wold be a better solution to save the data in a worktable in first place instead? I don't really know why the solution is with global temp tables.